# Bounding the total variation distance of two specific random variables?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent discrete random variables, and $Z$ be a function of $X$ and $Y$, i.e., $Z=f(X,Y)$. Suppose that $\Gamma$ is a set such that
$$\mathrm{Pr}[(X,Y)\in\Gamma]\geq 1-\epsilon$$
Now, we constitute $\tilde{Z}$ from $Z$ as follows
\begin{align}
\tilde{Z}=\begin{cases}
Z&(x,y)\in\Gamma\\
\star&(x,y)\in\Gamma^{c}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
where $\star$ is a realization of $\tilde{Z}$ which does not belong to sample space of $Z$.

Question:
Does the total variation distance between $p(z,x)$ and $q(\tilde{z},x)$ (joint pmfs) is small enough. In other words, is there any $\delta(\epsilon)$ goes to zero as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ such that
\begin{align}
\lVert p(x,z)-q(x,\tilde{z})\rVert_1=\sum_{(x,z\cup\star)}\lvert p(x,z)-q(x,\tilde{z}) \rvert\leq\delta(\epsilon)
\end{align}
where $p(x,\star)=0$. If there is not such a $\delta$, what is the best upper-bound for total variation term?

Comment: The sentence "$\star$ is a realization of $\tilde Z$ which does not belong to the sample space of $Z$"  seems a bit circular since $\star$ is used to define $\tilde Z$.  Also the joint PMFs are for which random variables?

Comment: I mean $\tilde{Z}$ is equal to $Z$ with probability $1-\epsilon$ and equal to $\star$ with probability $\epsilon$. $p(x,z)$ is joint pmf of $X$ and $Z$, and $q(x,\tilde{z})$ is joint pmf of $X$ and $\tilde{Z}$.

Comment: Is $\star$ a constant?

Comment: Yes, it is constant.

Comment: Doesn't the bound follow from the coupling interpretation of the TV distance, i.e., $d_{TV}(q,p) \le Pr( (X,Z) \ne (X, \tilde Z)) = \epsilon$?

Comment: But marginal pmf $p(z)$ is not equal to the marginal pmf $q(\tilde{z})$. Is not necessary?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50244/discussion-between-nawaf-bou-rabee-and-mohammad-mahdi).